# Save multiple data with same ID in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

I was trying to implement this process into my project. But, I find difficulty in finding the back-end code. The process is like this

[Bill Of Material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx3O2.png)

This form allow user to make multiple revision based on the Bill of Material ID, but all of the data is stored in database like this

[Bill of Material Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7VYt.png)

Can I know how is this possible, since the Bill of Material ID is primary key? And every time new data is stored, it doesn't overwrite the previous data. Thank you in advance

**Edit**: Basically what I was trying to do is to disable the update whenever I press save, and force it into insert new data

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the revision id and the BOM ID as composite keys?

Comment: I don't think its possible because revision number is no primary key and it doesn't suppose to be a primary key

Comment: Then create a new column for Primary key (Sequence) and make your BOM ID as a Foreign key

Comment: What are you expecting exactly? Can you show us some sample?

Comment: its in the 2nd picture. So for example I insert a data with BOM ID 0001, and the revision number is 0. And then I need to update data in BOM ID 0001, after I made the changes, I change the revision number into 1. In sql, both BOM ID 0001 data with revision number 0 and BOM ID 0001 with revision number 1 is stored and can be select for future information. I hope that makes sense

Comment: the keys cannot be changed as they table is part of an existing product. I think the issue here is a miss understanding on how the product functions rather than a development question.

Answer (score 0):

Being this module is from an ISV, you should consult with them on this process. If you turn off revision tracking in Bill of Material preferences, it will turn off the revision/multi record tracking feature (if this helps). The table keys in this scenario cannot be changed as it would break the ISV product and be replaced during the next package publish (removing your table changes). Revisions for this screen are tracked over date. Data for old revisions does not allow for update (view only)

**Edit:** I think in re-reading your question, you want to implement something similar in your own project? The code for this can be found in the customization project in the graph behind that page. Look at the Row events and the Persist call. The keys for the table is BOM and date.

For reference, look at BOMRevisionWrapper in the graph for Bill of Material. The idea here is it stores the updates as inserts in a seperate cache object and during persist saves them using a different graph. Not the best but it works. You can open the dll using  a decompiler such as justdecompile as shown in the image below.

[image: Persist on Bill of Material graph]

Comment: I think i didn't explain my question properly. Basically, what I was going to do is when I press save, instead of updating the data in the database, I want to make the save process to become inserting the data into the database.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want the save process to insert a new record with the changes and abort the update to the existing data (to preserve history)?

Comment: I think in re-reading your question, you want to implement something similar in your own project? The code for this can be found in the customization project in the graph behind that page. Look at the Row events and the Persist call. The keys for the table is BOM and date.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't find the code anywhere, and that project doesn't even show the DAC, that's why I need help to implement this. I get the idea to disabling the update and force to insert, but don't know the way to do it

Comment: The code is in the dll within the customization project. Use a decompiler such as JustDecompile. You actually need to perform the update, but also do an insert but change the values of the 2 rows (1 update and 1 insert) so they align with the changes and the keys are set correctly (date in this case)